# Returning data from UIViewController in a UIPopoverController when popover is dismissed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a second view controller set to display in a UIPopoverController. I set up a delegate in the second view controller so when the user taps the button "Done", it passes the data back to the first view controller. The data is a list of selections the user makes, its not a single selection.

i'm having trouble figuring out a way to pass that data back to the first view controller if the user tap's outside of the pop over and is dismissed. right now, if the user taps out side of the pop over and it gets dismissed, i lose the data.

i suppose i could restrict them from dismissing the pop over by tapping outside of it, but i'd rather not.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you present the `UIPopoverController`, set its `delegate` to be `self`

And then add to the class this function

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    YourViewController *controller =  popoverController.contentViewController;
    MyData *data = controller.yourData;
    //Do something with data
}
```

This function will be called when the popover is dismissed

Comment: I think you might need to implement "popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover" if you are concerned about the user dismissing the Popover by tapping outside of the popover instead.

Comment: yep, i have, but i don't believe i would have access to the second view controller's data from there...

Comment: ha! awesome, thanks! only note i'd make is you need to type cast the view controller or else you'll get a warning.